# A problem on linear independence of vectors in $F^n$ where $F$ is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Note that $F$ denotes a field of characteristic zero. First of all we define $a^\theta= a^{-1}$ if $a\ne 0$ and $0$ otherwise. With the help of this define $v^\theta$ for $v=(v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_n)\in F^n$ as $v^\theta= (v_1^\theta,v_2^\theta,\cdots, v_n^\theta)$ and a new type of product ( let me call it as transinner product) of vectors in $F^n$ as $[u,v]=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_iv_i^\theta$. Then I have the following questions. 1) What can we say about the linear independence of vectors ${w_1,w_2,\cdots, w_k}$ in $F^k$ when it is given that ${v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_k}$ in $F^n$ are linearly independent and each $w_i=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{k}[v_i, v_j]e_j$. 2) What is the geometrical interpretation of this product? (Recall that the usual inner product deals with orthogonality)

Comment: Dear Stefan. Note that the linearity with the second part is lost here when compared with the usual inner product. But still it has nice properties

Comment: Note that for $u=(x_1,y_1)\ne 0$ and $v=(x_2, y_2)\ne 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $[u,v]=x_1/x_2+y_1/y_2=0$ makes the reflection of points into play. What will be the same for $\mathbb{R}^3$